# Web Workbench intellisense and LESS variables file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, intellisense, less

I use a separate file just for variables in less. I also have a bootstrapping less file which imports all the other less files at compile time.

My question is, is there a way to tell Web Workbench to use the variables less file as a reference for it's intellisense? So that if I'm working in a less file that doesn't directly import the variables file, it will still detect the variable names in intellisense?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference path to your less file. This works in the same way as it would in a js file by giving you intellisense for that file.

**Example**

```
/// <reference path="variables.less" />

.bacon {
    color: @red; // Should have intellisense now.
}
```